# Detecting and intercepting video playback in SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, nsnotification, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am using SFSafariViewController in my app. When the user plays a video I have to show a pop up asking whether the user wants to download the videos. I have done this with UIWebView and AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification. But this is not working in SFSafariViewController. Can someone give me a solution to this?

Here is the code of adding observer to SFSafariViewController

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self.safariViewController!, selector: #selector(self.playerItemBecameCurrent), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification"), object: nil)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, this would not be possible in `SFSafariViewController`.

`SFSafariViewController` isn't open for inspection/interception like `UIWebView` and `WKWebView`. Given the control interfaces with the devices KeyChain it makes sense from a security standpoint too.

You very much can only give it a URL and a set of 2 customisable options.

Revert to a `WKWebView` or at worst, `UIWebView`.

Appreciate my answer is late, I hope you found it useful

Comment: i'm trying in WKWebView but not fired notification for avplayer